# How to create rewrite rules from apache to nginx

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I just start working with nginx, but i have problems with rewrite rules.
There is some of my .htaccess rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteRule ^cupinfo/(.*)$ /cup/?cupinfo=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^profile$ /cup/?profile=$1 [L]
```

I tried use my rewrites in nginx like this, but that didnt work, and i dont know where is the problem. Browser always says 404 error. My website is under "public_html/cup" directory, maybe there is the problem.

```
server {
        listen      80;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            root home/$2/public_html/cup;
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
        }

        location @rewrite {
            rewrite ^/cupinfo/(.*)$ /cup/?cupinfo=$1 last;
            rewrite ^/profile$ /cup/?profile=$1 last;
        }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have an undefined `$2` in your `root` directive, an undefined `$1` in your second `rewrite` directive, and you are rewriting to `public_html/cup/cup/index.php`, so maybe you have too many `/cup/`s in your request filename.

Comment: I am using winginx, i did all things what you said, but nginx anyway says "404 not found" when i go "localhost/cup/profile". http://pastebin.com/vR1GnE7T

Comment: What are we looking at now, your question or your pastebin? And what physical file do you expect the URI `/cup/profile` to find?